# How to restrict Apache Nutch 2.3.1 to crawl story content and not side bars

Tags: apache, hadoop, web-crawler, sitemap, nutch

I have to crawl some news websites. I have setup apache Nutch 2.3.1 with Hadoop 2.7.4 and Hbase cluster. I have to provide search via solr 6.6.1. After crawling some websites, I have observed that Nutch crawl everything in a page. In news websites, there are sidebars that contain latest or top news etc. These sidebar content changed with time. Is there any way to ask Nutch to crawl main story content and avoid such side bars.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you're using Nutch 2.x this is a bit difficult, for Nutch 1.x you could use the boilerpipe implementation that's available on Tika. But unfortunately, it's not ported to the 2.x branch yet.